# Implement Enum Instance behavior on custom data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've got a custom data type in Haskell to represent a traffic light

```
data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green
```

I'm attempting to implement the features of the **Enum** typeclass using an instance block like so:

```
instance Enum TrafficLight where
    succ Green = Yellow
    succ Yellow = Red
    succ Red = Green
    pred Green = Red
    pred Yellow = Green
    pred Red = Yellow
```

*pred* and *succ* work as expected, however I'd also like to implement the range function, such that I'd be able to call

```
ghci> [Green .. Red]
```

and have it return

```
[Green,Yellow,Red]
```

I understand that this functionality seems to come from the **enumFrom** function in the **Enum** typeclass, but I'm not completely sure how to implement it the say way I implemented *pred* and *succ*.

Comment: The minimal implementation is actually not sufficient for bounded types, because it doesn't provide a stopping condition for the notations `[x ..]` and `[.. y]` https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18400011.2 And the cyclic behavior of `succ` and `pred`, even if not forbidden outright, doesn't seem anticipated by the spec of `Enum`. So not relying on `Enum` for it seems less dangerous.

Comment: And, extending @Li-yaoXia's commentary, cyclic behavior *is* [forbidden outright](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4) for types that also instantiate `Bounded`. Perhaps you can get away with it if you don't implement `Bounded`... but then, if you do implement `Ord` it seems likely somebody will want `Bounded` at some point for something, so you should probably avoid `Ord` as well, and at that point I think you might just want to use a different class than `Enum` altogether to avoid this morass.

Comment: Are you intentionally not using `deriving`?

Answer (score 0):

The description for `enumFrom` at haskell.org gives the following possible definition `enumFrom n = n : enumFrom (succ n)`. It should work in your case.